# How do I get a print output as a list from a manipulated loop?, Or, get same result without print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have ten tables named t1,... t10. I would like to use variables for name of tables . The codes are:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print("t",i, sep='', end=', ')

 Output is: t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10,
 I will use like this: im.execute("delete from ' + b[1] + '"). So,
 I need a list b=["t1", "t2", ..... "t10"]
```

How do I get this output as a list?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a list comprehension with similar logic to generate the list you are looking for.

For example:

```
items = [f't{i}' for i in range(1,11)]
print(items)
# OUTPUT
# ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 't7', 't8', 't9', 't10']

# You could also do ['t{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,11)] if you are pre python 3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ts = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    ts.append('t{}'.format(i))
```

Or, in one line:

```
ts = ['t{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 11)]
```